# How do I Join a table with an ID field to another table with pivoted fields

Tags: sql-server

ID table:

```
A283240
B490382
B449200
C243456
```

Codes table:

```
Code1
Code2
Code3
Code4
Code5
```

Desired Result:

```
Id      Code1   Code2   Code3   Code4   Code5
A283240 Null    Null    Null    Null    Null
B490382 Null    Null    Null    Null    Null
B449200 Null    Null    Null    Null    Null
C243456 Null    Null    Null    Null    Null
```

There will be 7000+ Code columns eventually required. I will go back and populate the null cells w/ a "1", "2" or "NA" flag. I have dabbled with dynamic SQL to pivot half of the 7000 codes successfully. SQL Server gave me some error about being over a 4100 record limit or thereabouts. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Unpivot the data first, then do the `JOIN`.

Comment: Also, **why** is your `Codes` table denormalized like this?

Comment: "*SQL Server gave me some error about being over a 4100 record limit or thereabouts.*" - Having the exact error would be helpful.

Comment: This is a completely horrible way to store this data. It should have just two columns `Id, Code` and possibly a third `CodeNumber` column which would store the number per ID. Do not denormalize like this, it is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.